# which of the following is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

consider   the group $\mathbb{Z}^2  =\{(a,b)| a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ under               component wise addition.

then which of the following is a  subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

$a)$ $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 | ab=0\}$

$b)$ $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 | 3a +2b=15\}$

$c)$ $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 |\text{7 divides ab}\}$

$d)$ $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 |\text{2 divides a and 3 divides b}\}$

My attempts  :

I know  that  under               component wise addition will be $(a,b)  + (a,b)= (2a,2b)$

Here  $2$ is  Divide  $a$.  Now  i can not  proceed further

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Do you know how to check/prove that a subset of a group is a subgroup?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : A non empty subset  $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup of  $G $ iff for every  $x,y \in H$, $xy^{-1} \in H $.